# RESTEasy JAX-RS Nullpointer when I try to reach my Controller class from another package

Tags: maven, cdi, resteasy, inject, java-ee-8

I'm setting up a Maven project (in Java EE) based on a basic BCE-Pattern.
Within the "Boundary"-Package i started to specify several JAX-RS Apis using RESTeasy.
If I send a POST, GET or whatever to this APIs they should delegate the request to the controller classes which then basically do all the work.

But whenever the Boundary (Api) sends a request to the Controller (Service) I face Nullpointer Exceptions like:

```
2020-07-02T13:45:15.987+0200|Info: Try to post User alexhuckerman
2020-07-02T13:45:15.994+0200|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Resteasy]: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at boundary.UserApi.postUser(UserApi.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:638)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:504)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:454)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:456)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:417)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:488)
    ... 37 more
```

**My POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.wm</groupId>
<artifactId>workflowManager</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>workflowManager Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-servlet-initializer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <glassfishDirectory>C:\Users\AlexanderCimander\Documents\Master@IBM\Uni\glassfish5\glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>admin</user>
                <passwordFile>files\password.txt</passwordFile>
                <domain>
                    <name>domain1</name>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                    <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <strong>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                </strong>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>C:XXXXX\glassfish5\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--host=localhost</argument>
                    <argument>--port=4848</argument>
                    <argument>--user=admin</argument>
                    <argument>--passwordfile=files/password.txt</argument>
                    <argument>--interactive=false</argument>
                    <argument>--echo=true</argument>
                    <argument>--terse=true</argument>
                    <argument>add-resources</argument>
                    <argument>--upload=true</argument>
                    <argument>files/glassfish-resources.xml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**My Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>workflowmanager</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>boundary.ApplicationServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.wider.request.matching</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**My Beans.xml** (Placed under scr/main/webapp/WEB-INF)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="all"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
</beans>
```

**My ApplicationServlet**

```
    package boundary;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class ApplicationServlet extends Application{
    
     private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        public ApplicationServlet() {
            singletons.add(new UserApi());
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            return classes;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
            return singletons;
        }
    
}
```

**My UserApi**

```
    package boundary;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import control.UserService;
import entity.User;

@Path("user")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class UserApi{
    
    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    // Create a Logger
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserApi.class.getName());

    /*
     * Will be called by a Rest-Client. This userApi then redirects the call from the client to the userService.
     * After Processing the call this userApi will then respond to the client.
     * 
     * Example Path to make a call: http://localhost:8080/workflowmanager/api/user/
     */

    /**
     * API method to post an user
     *
     * @param user
     * @return {@link Response} containing the status of the request and (in case of
     *         success) also the requested contract information
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postUser(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @Valid final User user) throws Exception {

        // create User
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Try to post User %s", user.getUsername()));
        final User createdUser = userService.createUser(user);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("User %s successfully created", createdUser.getUsername()));

        return Response.created(null).build();
    }

    /**
     * API method to update an user
     *
     * @param user
     * @return {@link Response} containing the status of the request and (in case of
     *         success) also the requested contract information
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{username}")
    public Response putUser(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @Valid final User user,
            @PathParam("username") final String userName) throws Exception {

        // avoid change of username
        if (!userName.equals(user.getUsername())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Not allowed to change username!");
        }

        // update User
        final User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(user);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("User %s successfully updated", updatedUser.getUsername()));

        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    /**
     * API method to get an user
     *
     * @param userName
     * @return {@link Response} containing the status of the request and (in case of
     *         success) also the requested contract information
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{userName}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userName") final String userName) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Looking up User %s", userName));
        final User user = userService.getUser(userName);
        return Response.ok(user).build();
    }
    
    /**
       * API method to deregister an user
       *
       * @param username
       * @return  {@link Response} containing the status of the request and (in case of
     *         success) also the requested contract information
       * @throws Exception
       */
      @Transactional(rollbackOn =Exception.class)
      @DELETE
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Path("/{userName}")
      public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("userName") final String userName) throws Exception {

       userService.deleteContract(userName);
        return Response.noContent().build();
      }
}
```

**My UserService**

```
package control;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;

import entity.User;

@Stateless
public class UserService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "workflowManager")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    // Create a Logger
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserService.class.getName());

    /*
     * Hier werden die Anfragen von der userApi (Boundary) ankommen und die Daten
     * manipuliert. Ebenfalls wird hier mit der Datenbank gesprochen
     */

    /**
     * Creates a new User
     * 
     * @param user
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public User createUser(final User user) throws Exception {

        // check preconditions
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Checking if user with name %s already exists ", user.getUsername()));
        if (getUser(user.getUsername()) != null) {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("User %s already exists! Persisting process aborted.", user.getUsername()));
            throw new Exception(new InternalError("Something went wrong during the creation of an user"));
        }

        // save
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Creating user with name ", user.getUsername()));
        this.entityManager.persist(user);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("User %s successfully persisted", user.getUsername()));

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a given user
     *
     * @param user
     * @throws ElcException
     */
    public User updateUser(final User user) throws Exception {
        User existingUser = null;
        final String userName = user.getUsername();
        if (userName != null) {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Searching for User with userName %s before updating", user.getUsername()));
            existingUser = getUser(userName);
        } else {
            throw new Exception(new InternalError("Something went wrong during the update of an user"));
        }
        user.setId(existingUser.getId());
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Merging user with username ", user.getUsername()));
        final User mergedUser = this.entityManager.merge(user);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("updated username with username %s", user.getUsername()));

        return mergedUser;

    }

    /**
     * Get all available Users as list
     *
     * @return List<User>
     */
    public List<User> getAllUser() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Retrieving all User ...");
        try {
            final List<User> user = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(User.FIND_ALL, User.class).getResultList();
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Getting all users failed %s", e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets one user by username
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public User getUser(final String userName) throws Exception {
        // Retrieve contractOwner and check if owner exists.

        LOGGER.info(String.format("try to get user with name %s", userName));

        try {
            // get user
            return this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(User.FIND_BY_USERNAME, User.class)
                    .setParameter("username", userName).getSingleResult();

        } catch (final NoResultException e) {
            // user not found
            LOGGER.info(String.format("No user %s found! Error Message: %s", userName, e.getMessage()));
            throw new NotFoundException();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Sorry something went wrong - No user %s found! Error Message: %s", userName,
                    e.getMessage()));
            throw new Exception(new InternalError("Something went wrong while retreiving an user"));
        }

    }
    
    /**
     * Deletes one user by username
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
     public void deleteContract(final String userName) throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Deleting user %s", userName));
            final User user = getUser(userName);

            try {
            // delete from database
            this.entityManager.remove(user);

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info(String.format("Sorry something went wrong - user %s could not be deleted! Error Message: %s", userName,
                        e.getMessage()));
                throw new Exception(new InternalError("Sorry something went wrong - user could not be deleted!"));
            }

            LOGGER.info(String.format("User successfully removed.", user.getUsername()));
          }

}
```

**My User**

```
    package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * The persistent class for the "USER" database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"), 
@NamedQuery(name = User.FIND_BY_USERNAME,
query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :userName")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    static final String PREFIX = "workflowManager.entity.User.";
    public static final String FIND_ALL = PREFIX + "findAll";
    public static final String FIND_BY_USERNAME = PREFIX + "findByUsername";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    @NotNull(message = "password is required")
    @Size(max = 255, message = "password is too long")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    @NotNull(message = "role is required")
    @Size(max = 255, message = "role is too long")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    @NotNull(message = "username is required")
    @Size(max = 255, message = "username is too long")
    private String username;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Coderepotarget
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODEREPOTARGET")
    private Coderepotarget coderepotargetBean;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Workflowtooltarget
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORKFLOWTOOLTARGET")
    private Workflowtooltarget workflowtooltargetBean;

    public User() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Coderepotarget getCoderepotargetBean() {
        return this.coderepotargetBean;
    }

    public void setCoderepotargetBean(Coderepotarget coderepotargetBean) {
        this.coderepotargetBean = coderepotargetBean;
    }

    public Workflowtooltarget getWorkflowtooltargetBean() {
        return this.workflowtooltargetBean;
    }

    public void setWorkflowtooltargetBean(Workflowtooltarget workflowtooltargetBean) {
        this.workflowtooltargetBean = workflowtooltargetBean;
    }

}
```

**Some more information:**
After hours of trying to get the userService doing the work I tried to do all the logic within the UserApi itself. I added the persistance-context to the userApi and instanciated the EntityManager. I got another NPE while I tried to use the EntityManager.

I deploy the app on glassfish5 using the command `mvn clean install`

I also tried several other Commands like Maven->Update Project, mvn clean, project clean and I already restarted Eclipse multiple times etc.

I use CDI 1.0 and a Dynamic Webmodule 3.0 but when I start the server it tells me (without bigger issues):

```
BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.servlet.internal.CdiExternalRequestScope is deprecated from CDI 1.1! [..]
```

I feel like something really strange is going on there as well?

For now I'm super confused and frustrated, maybe you guys know what is missing.

Comment: You are doing `singletons.add(new UserApi());`, so CDI has no chance to inject this instance. You have luck adding the *class*, ie `classes.add(UserApi.class);`. Or you can leave the system to discover your JAX-RD resources automatically.

Comment: hey @NikosParaskevopoulos, thank you for your fast response! You are absoluetly right, I tried your classe.add() version, didn't help. After that I cleaned the whole web.xml and added the ApplicationPath(/api/*) to ApplicationServlet (and removed all the classes.add() stuff. I then faced: 

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData&#40;Ljava/lang/Class&#59;&#41;Ljava/lang/Object&#59;

Comment: As Nikos already mentioned, if you bypass CDI with object-creation, you'll never have injection working. However, I also don't see resteasy-cdi in your pom, so probably you have not setup resteasy correctly. The concrete dependencies and setup steps are server-dependent, so try to search for "resteasy cdi <yourserver>" and try to find a step-by-step setup guide.

Answer (score 0):

Allright so thank you at @Nikos and @mtj!

As it turns out my Glassfish server and the newest versions of Resteasy and Java are quite facing some dependency issues.

After hours of debugging dependencies I decided to switch to Jersey.

But @Nikos advice was completely right! If you want to go with an ApplicationServlet make sure to either use `classes.add(UserApi.class)` or just leave the ApplicationServlet empty and hope for your system to find it on its own!

Jersey for example tells me in the Console which classes it has found as servlet so make sure to check the logs as well! :-)